# Alert Dialog Message

Tags: android

I am using an `if-else` statement. If the username and password are correct it goes to the next activity but if they are incorrect I want an alert dialog message to be displayed and when ok is clicked I want to return to this login page. I would appreciate some help *

This is my code,

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
   Button button;
   private EditText uname;
   private EditText passw;
   String usern;
   String pass;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        passw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

   }
   public void onClick(View v) {

           usern = uname.getText().toString();
           pass = passw.getText().toString();

           if((usern == "xyz")&&(pass=="xyz")){
               Intent i = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),TrackMap.class);
               startActivity(i);
           }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code to implement the alert dialogue in android. Put this code in your else block.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("Error")
.setMessage("Incorrect combination of Username and passowrd"+"\nPlease try again")
.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // This button will do nothing it will just dismiss the dialog.
    }
 })
//You can set this icon by having any error image in your drawable or you can just get rid of the next line.
.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert) 
.show();
```

Hope this helped.

**Update**

You are incorrectly comparring two strings in your if block which will cause errors or probably the if condition will never be true. Please refer to the following code for correct way. You should not user `==` to compare two strings, as `==` compares literal values and not objects. There us a method in `String` class called `equals()` which compares two strings.

***Code***

change your if condition to this.

```
if((usern.equals("xyz"))&&(pass.equals("xyz"))){
    //Add your code block here
}
```

Comment: did you change your if condition as I mentioned?? because the way you are putting the if condition it will never be true and hence else block will get executed always.